# Why is christianity.meta.stackexchange.com the only option for recommending a different SE site for a question?

Tags: feature-request, migration

It seems that the majority of questions on Christianity SE that get moved end up in hermeneutics SE.  But this is not an option when voting to close a question because it belongs on another SE site - only christianity.meta appears as an option.

Is this just a legacy from before hermeneutics SE was available, or is it intentional?